# class added to div prints extra pages confusion

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to set a small 5 lines of text part of a webpage that is the middle of my query mobile page as the only printing part of the page, the end goal is to print it on a 62mm x 52mm brother label printer label.

Here's the CSS I have:

```
@page {
        size: 62mm 52mm;
        margin: 0;
    }
.print:last-child {
     page-break-after: auto;
}

@media print {    
    .no-print, .no-print * {
        display: none !important;
    }
    
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    .page, .page * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    .page {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        
        display:block;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
        height: 99%;
        padding: 0;
        transform: rotate(270deg);
    }
}
```

So in all of the divs I don't want to print I use the class="no-print" class and the part I'm printing I use the class="page" class.

```
<div class="page" data-role="content" >
                <p align="center"><?php echo $_SESSION['prod_name'];?></p>
                <p align="center">#<?php echo $_SESSION['prod_no'];?></p>
                <p align="center" ><?php echo date("d / m / y",strtotime($_SESSION['date']));?></p>
                <br>
                <p align="center"><?php echo $_SESSION['result1'];?></p>
                <p align="center"><?php echo $_SESSION['result2'];?></p>
</div>
```

I have tried many different things in order to solve this problem and just when I assumed it was a Jquery Mobile issue **I tried something quite random, I applied the class to a paragraph instead of the div, this wanted to print only on one page only** instead of the three pages that the div keeps showing.

Is there something really simple I'm missing here? Have I gone the wrong way about this or is this perhaps some kind of known bug using Jquery Mobile?

Despite using the developer tools in a couple of web browsers to try and identify padding or margin issues I am now stuck, this would be great if anyone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the extra div's not to be on the print page, in my opinion, add `opacity:0 !important;` to your code and try again.

```
 .no-print, .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```